# Core Data convert a superclass instance into a subclass instance?

Tags: iphone, core-data, subclass, nsmanagedobject, superclass

What's the best way to programmatically convert an `NSManagedObject`-subclass (`User`) instance into an instance of its subclass (`AccountUser`)?

#### Setup

`AccountUser` inherits from `User` : `NSManagedObject`

When I sign up or log into the app for the first time, I become an `AccountUser`. Then, I download all of my friends and store them as `User` objects.

Both `User` & `AccountUser` have attributes `firstName`, `lastName`, etc. `AccountUser` has some extra things, like `accessToken`.

#### Problem

My friend John logs in on my device. Since he's my friend, he's already stored as a `User`. But now, I want to convert him into an `AccountUser`. What's the best way to do this programmatically? I have lots of attributes and relationships to preserve, so creating a new `AccountUser` object from a `User` object and then deleting the original `User` object is a lot to do. If I just create an `AccountUser` without deleting the `User`, things get messy. E.g. when I fetch `User` by ID, I get two objects back: one is the `AccountUser`, the other is the `User`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is to simply create a new AccountUser object and copy the relevant fields from the existing User object into it. Then deal with the old User object appropriately -- delete it, save it, whatever makes sense. It'd make sense to give AccountUser an initializer that takes an instance of User, like `-initWithUser:`.

Another (probably better) option would involve using a single class (User) for all users. If there's additional information to be stored for some users (currently AccountUsers), create a new Account class and associate an instance of Account with the users that require it. So the User objects that represent you and your friend John would each have associated Account objects, and all the other users wouldn't. When one of your other friends logs into your phone, you can create a new Account object for that person and associate it with their existing User object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it this way

1. Add the User entity a boolean property called "is_account_user".
2. Set a relationship between User and account user.
3. if a user has an account user, create the AcountUser entity and relate it to the User.

If the user has no account info then the "is_account_user" will be NO;

When you fetch for a user you can check if is_account_user is YES, and if so you can get his AcountUser with the relationship.

Hope it helps